# Code doesn't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm using the following code to remove "http://" and "https://" from an user entered/pasted URL in a textbox:

```
$('input.url-input').change(

       function()
       {
           var textbox = $(this);

           if (textbox.val().indexOf("http://") == 0)
               textbox.val(textbox.val().substring(7));

           if (textbox.val().indexOf("https://") == 0)
               textbox.val(textbox.val().substring(8));

       });
```

My problem is it works in all browsers, including IE9 & IE10, but not in IE8.

I'm new to Javascript and would appreciate your help.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "Not workig" means what? Nothing happens? Unexpected results? An error is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works in IE7,8 use jQuery <= 1.10.x not 2.0.x

```
$('input[type=text].input-url').change( 
  function(event) {
      var $input, url;

      $input = $(this);
      url = $input.val();
      $input.val(url.replace(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)/i,''));          
 });
```

or short

```
  $('input[type=text].input-url').change(  
    function(event) {
      $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)/i,''));
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a million, diproart!